# Looping through checkboxes and subtracting a value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a series of checkboxes and each is worth a different amount of points that I want to deduct from a total of 100 if the box is not checked. The point value is designated by the CSS class of the checkbox. In this example, each box is worth 10 points so if both remain checked, the point value = 100, 1 unchecked = 90, 2 unchecked = 80 etc.  Similarly, if a user decides to check the box back again, I need to add the 10 points back to the total.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('[class*="Score"]').change(function () {
    calculateScore();
});

function calculateScore() {
    var total = 100;
    $(".Score10").each(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked)')) {
            total += 10;
        } else {
            total -= 10;
        }});

<asp:CheckBox ID="chkScore_Greeting" runat="server" CssClass="Score10" 
Checked="true" /> 
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkScore_Authentication" runat="server" 
CssClass="Score10" Checked="true" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've given you two flavors of the same thing.  Both implement the "each worth different points" thing using the built-in dataset properties of DOM elements.

Version 1: Subtract the weight of anything not checked from 100.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(document).on('change', '.Score', function() {
    var score = 100 - $('.Score:not(:checked)').toArray().reduce(
      (acc, cur) => acc + parseInt(cur.dataset.weight), 0);
    console.log(score);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="thing1" data-weight="10" class="Score" checked="true"/>1<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="thing2" data-weight="5" class="Score" checked="true"/>2<br />
```

Version 2: Modify the current score by the weight of the checkbox that was selected/unselected.

```js
var score = 100;

$(document).ready(function () {
  $(document).on('change', '.Score', function() {
    score += parseInt(this.dataset.weight) * (this.checked?1:-1)
    console.log(score);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="thing1" data-weight="10" class="Score" checked="true"/>1<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="thing2" data-weight="5" class="Score" checked="true"/>2<br />
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is two-fold.

First, you need to set your variable `total` **outside** of the function `calcuateScore()`. As it stands, whenever your checkboxes change, the `total` gets set to `100`, and **then** the logic triggers.

Second, your jQuery toggle won't work as you're passing in the wrong `$(this)` reference (as you want the one you **clicked** on, not to loop over each of them). In order to resolve this, you'll want to pass through the JavaScript version of `this` as a parameter in the call to `calculateScore()`. Then you can just check whether that element is checked with `.ischecked`.

This can be seen in the following working example, where I've substituted the ASP checkboxes for HTML ones:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('[class*="Score"]').change(function() {
    calculateScore(this);
  });

  var total = 100;

  function calculateScore(checkbox) {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      total += 10;
    } else {
      total -= 10;
    }
    console.log(total);
  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" class="Score10" checked="true" />
<input type="checkbox" class="Score10" checked="true" />
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Yes, it does.  Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

Stop adding 10.  You are already starting with 100.  The only thing left to do is subtract 10 for each one that is not checked. In other words, you only need the "else" part of your condition.